# Return search results fields by a mapping document using ElasticSearch

Tags: java, lucene, elasticsearch

I am indexing the following document as follows:

```
{
            "_index": "transactions",
            "_type": "transaction",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "another backup",
               "action": "3"
            }
         }
```

Now let's assume I have a another static document which holds all mappings for the actions:

```
{
            "_index": "transactions",
            "_type": "actions",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "3": "backup",
               "2": "upload",
               "1": "AnotherAction"
            }
         },
```

1. Is it possible to configure ES so when it returns document of type: /transactions/transaction/?

It will map the action field value into the value which stored at transactions/actions/1 ?

So when I do `GET /transactions/transaction/_search`

Ill get something like this:

```
{
                "_index": "transactions",
                "_type": "transaction",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                   "title": "another backup",
                   "action": "backup"
                }
             }
```

If it's possible how I do that? if not what other way is possible to index such documents with properties values as "enums" while knowing that their values might change in the future.

thanks,
ray.

Comment: Evenn though its possible to use Elasticsearch as a database, its generally considered a better idea to store your data in an actual database, whether SQL or nosql, and just retrieve the key from ES, and then use the database's facilities to retrieve the data, including the 'join' that you want here.

Comment: But we are using ES a sour primary DB. there isnt a way to normalize specific fields?